# How to change the pop html on button click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to find a way to change the pop up HTML on a chrome extension to another one when you click a button. I have tried to make a onclick function href but nothing works. I am new to both HTML and chrome extensions so I am sorry if this problem seems easy to the more experience developers.

```
 <form id="gform" method="POST" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" data-email="from_email@example.com"
       action="https://script.google.com/a/cvsd356.org/macros/s/AKfycbxb4ZyUUQCnTN-7iYF-YRViDSy/exec">

    <div class="name">
      name: <input type="text" name="Name" id= "inputbox"><br>
    </div>

    <div class="id">
        ID# <input type="text" name= "ID" id= "inputbox"><br>
    </div>

    <div class="MailingAddress">
        Mailing Address: <input type="text" name= "Mailing Adresss" id= "inputbox"  style=width:350px;><br>
    </div>

    <div class="sendToTr">
        Send Transcript to: <input type ="text" name="College"  style=width:350px; id= "inputbox" ><br>
    </div>

    <div class="emailmy">
      <label for="email"><em>Your</em> Email Address:</label>
      <input id="inputbox" name="email" type="email" value=""
          required placeholder="your.name@email.com" />
    </div>

    <div class="sButton">
      <button style=height:30px;width:70px;border-radius: 3px; class="button-success pure-button button-xlarge">
        send
      </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share some code for what the button mark up looks like at this point?

Comment: <button style=height:30px;width:70px;border-radius: 3px;  class="button-success pure-button button-xlarge" ></button>

Comment: Please edit your Question and add the code there!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are quite a few ways to achieve what you are asking. If I were you, I would add a JavaScript file to my project to do this.

### **Step 1**:

I would tell my HTML page where to find this JS file. The sample below can be included near the end of your HTML file, right before `</body></html>`. The sample below assumes your new popup.js file is in the root folder of your project:

```
<script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### **Step 2**:

In the popup.js file, I would create a function that tells the popup how it should be modified. In the sample below, I'm going to hide the element with an ID of `"theOldElement"` and show the element with an ID of `"theNewElement"`. I'm also going to attach this function to the click event of `"theButton"` element.

**popup.js**

```
function updatePopup(){
      document.getElementById("theNewElement").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("theOldElement").style.display = "none";

}
document.getElementById('theButton').addEventListener('click', updatePopup);
```

### **Step 3**:

I like referring to my HTML elements by ID (as I've been doing above - note the "getElementById" references), so I would:

- add `id="theNewElement"` to the element I want to reveal
- add `id="theOldElement"` to the element I want to hide
- add `id="theButton"` to the button that I want to trigger this change
- **Note**: you can insert these IDs as the first attribute within the tag you want to identify. E.g., `<div id="theNewElement" ...`